# how to keep a filename with only 20 characters and a file extension .txt

Tags: filenames, rename

I have a bunch of files like this:

```
hhsLog.8020.20200330}1585594173}0}coll_DefaultCollectorGroup_1_158594166_132642}1036942}0}0
```

I just want to keep the first 20 characters and add a `.txt` extension. So in the end I should have a file with the name:

```
hhsLog.8020.20200330.txt
```

I am working on both Fedora and Solaris.

Answer (score 11):

You can easily do this with a shell loop in `bash`:

```
cd /path/to/files/;
for file in *; do
    echo mv -i -- "$file" "${file:0:20}.txt"
done
```

Once you are satisfied that does what you need, remove the echo to actually rename the files:

```
 cd /path/to/files/;
 for file in *; do
    mv -i -- "$file" "${file:0:20}.txt"
done
```

The `-i` will make `mv` ask before overwriting if one of the new names already exists.

Comment: `$file` will include its path (`/path/to/files/`) which will incorrectly count towards the 20 characters.

Comment: @PaulEvans oh wow, yes indeed. Fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora and Solaris support bash shell:

With **'for'** loop sometimes, without processing the path and filename individually, it will process the first 20 characters of the path mentioned but not the actual filenames.

So this will do the exact thing what you want to do, will not go to subdirectories ( if you want subdirectories to be processed, remove the  '-maxdepth 0' option:

```
find /path/of/the/files/* -maxdepth 0 -type f| xargs -I[] bash -c 'val="[]";file=${val##*/};newfile=${file:0:20};mv $val ${val%/*}/$newfile.txt'
```

The **-I** option in xargs replaces each filename(including path) found with "**[]**", and we are executing bash commands against each **[]->filename** where we store this in **$val** variable and extract path and filenames , get first 20 characters of filename alone and moving it like "mv fullpath-with-filename    fullpath-withoutfilename/first20charcters-of-filename".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all relevant filenames matches `hhslog.*` in the current directory. Then, using the Perl `rename` utility:

```
rename  's/(.{20}).*/$1.txt/' hhsLog.*
```

This applies the Perl substitution `s/(.{20}).*/$1.txt/` to each filename.  This truncates the names at 20 characters and then also adds a `.txt` filename suffix.

To truncate the names at the first `}`, use

```
rename  's/([^}]+).*/$1.txt/' hhsLog.*
```

or

```
rename -n 's/(.+?)}.*/$1.txt/' hhsLog.*
```

To truncate the names at the first character that is not a word character or a dot, use

```
rename 's/([\w.]+).*/$1.txt/' hhsLog.*
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked:

```
for file in *
 do
 file2=$(echo ${file} | cut -c 1-20)
 mv ${file} ${file2}.txt
 done
```